# Aligning three paragraphs side by side HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have seen this question asked before but all the answers do not work. Here is the issue, I created three paragraphs, placed them under a div tag called end. I later use CSS in the following way:

```
#end{
background-color:#AEAEAE;
border:#FFFFFF;
border-width:thin;
border-style:solid;
padding: 50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-bottom: 13em;
}

#end p{
display-inline:block;
float: left;
padding:1em;
}
```

I have tried float left; changing the padding around/width/height. It just keeps coming out funny. I am using dreamweaver if that matters.

Comment: did u try setting the width as 33.33%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p1kuzzdo/2/

```
#end {
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    border: thin solid #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 13em;
    width: 100%;
}

#end p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 33.333%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. because you're adding padding; Use box-sizing to maintain the size of the p tags.
2. set the width on the p tags to a third of the width

```css
#end{
background-color:#AEAEAE;
border:#FFFFFF;
border-width:thin;
border-style:solid;
padding: 50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-bottom: 13em;
  
}

#end p{
display-inline:block;
float: left;
padding:1em;
  
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 33.3%
}
```

```html
<div id="end">
  <p>Fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p> 
  <p>Fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p> 
  <p>Fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Anji, just stole my boxsizing and got the correct answer vote!